# Increase container size and application master memory in HiveWarehouseSession

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Can we increase tez container size and application master memory through HiveWarehouseSession in spark.

Properties:-

`tez.am.resource.memory.mb`
`hive.tez.container.size`

Sample Code

```py
from pyspark_llap import HiveWarehouseSession
hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()
hive.setDatabase("sample_db")
hive.executeQuery("select abc from sample")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, below is how to do it in spark,

```
from pyspark_llap import HiveWarehouseSession
hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()
hive.setDatabase("sample_db")
hive.executeQuery("SET tez.am.resource.memory.mb=1024")
hive.executeQuery("SET hive.tez.container.size=3072")
hive.executeQuery("SELECT abc FROM sample")
```

Comment: Not through SqlContext or sparkSession. My Source is a bucketed table so I am reading through HiveWarehouseSession. like below 

```from pyspark_llap import HiveWarehouseSession```
```hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()```
```hive.setDatabase("sample_db")```
```hive.executeQuery("select abc from sample")```

Comment: Original question was just setting the mentioned hive properties, and not this one. Edit your question with right content.

Comment: I have mentioned through HiveWarehouseSession in the title itself. Updated the sample code as per your request.

Comment: It is throwing parse exception.

Stack Trace : 

`ERROR HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader: Unable to read table schema
 File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.executeQuery.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:4 cannot recognize input near 'SET' 'tez' '.' in statement`